# JS Html Entity Decoding (jquery 1.7.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

With the latest update, the following code broke. It doesnt append the code in lb_l_ret.lbcode anymore. This code however, is html entities escaped. How can I make it work? Or how can I decode those html entities in javascript? A good regular expression to decode htmlentities is fine also!

```
if (lb_l_ret.show_once>0){
    createCookie("arevico_lb", "1", lb_l_ret.show_once);
}
var decoded = $j("<div/>").html(lb_l_ret.lbcode).text();
$j('body').append(decoded);
```

LB ret contains option data and is unfortunately encoded into htmlentities. for example:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var lb_l_ret = {
    lbcode: "&lt;a id=&quot;inline&quot; href=&quot;#data&quot; style=&quot;display: none;&quot;&gt;Show&lt;/a&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;display:none&quot;&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;data&quot; style=&quot;background-color:white;overflow:hidden;&quot;&gt;&lt;iframe src=&quot;//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=287663154583826&amp;width=400&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; style=&quot;border:none; overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:258px;&quot; allowTransparency=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
    delay: "3000",
    show_once: "20"
};
/* ]]> */
```

Comment: i dont know how you precisely call it, but I have added an example of lb_l_ret. it basically contains options in javascript.

Comment: When you remove the `iframe` in the markup (which Firebug reports as a permission violation), it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FssET/ Note, I also removed the `display: none` on the first `a` tag so we could see it.

Answer (score 1):

No JQuery and no DOM needed. Can be slow.:

```
    /**
     * By Caio Santos
     * newcaiosantos@gmail.com
     * Tabela utilizada:
     * http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp
     * Acesse game4game.com.br
     */
    function html_entity_decode(str){

        var replaceAll = function(str, find, replace) {
          return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
        }

        str = replaceAll(str,"&amp;","&");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&lt;","<");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&gt;",">");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&nbsp;"," ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&iexcl;","¡");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&cent;","¢");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&pound;","£");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&curren;","¤");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&yen;","¥");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&brvbar;","¦");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sect;","§");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&uml;","¨");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&copy;","©");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ordf;","ª");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&laquo;","«");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&not;","¬");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&shy;","");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&reg;","®");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&macr;","¯");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&deg;","°");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&plusmn;","±");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sup2;","²");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sup3;","³");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&acute;","´");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&micro;","µ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&para;","¶");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&middot;","·");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&cedil;","¸");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sup1;","¹");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ordm;","º");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&raquo;","»");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&frac14;","¼");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&frac12;","½");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&frac34;","¾");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&iquest;","¿");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Agrave;","À");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Aacute;","Á");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Acirc;","Â");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Atilde;","Ã");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Auml;","Ä");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Aring;","Å");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&AElig;","Æ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ccedil;","Ç");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Egrave;","È");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Eacute;","É");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ecirc;","Ê");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Euml;","Ë");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Igrave;","Ì");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Iacute;","Í");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Icirc;","Î");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Iuml;","Ï");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ETH;","Ð");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ntilde;","Ñ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ograve;","Ò");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Oacute;","Ó");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ocirc;","Ô");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Otilde;","Õ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ouml;","Ö");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&times;","×");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Oslash;","Ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ugrave;","Ù");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Uacute;","Ú");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Ucirc;","Û");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Uuml;","Ü");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Yacute;","Ý");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&THORN;","Þ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&szlig;","ß");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&agrave;","à");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&aacute;","á");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&acirc;","â");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&atilde;","ã");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&auml;","ä");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&aring;","å");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&aelig;","æ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ccedil;","ç");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&egrave;","è");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&eacute;","é");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ecirc;","ê");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&euml;","ë");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&igrave;","ì");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&iacute;","í");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&icirc;","î");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&iuml;","ï");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&eth;","ð");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ntilde;","ñ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ograve;","ò");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&oacute;","ó");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ocirc;","ô");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&otilde;","õ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ouml;","ö");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&divide;","÷");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&oslash;","ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ugrave;","ù");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&uacute;","ú");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ucirc;","û");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&uuml;","ü");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&yacute;","ý");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&thorn;","þ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&yuml;","ÿ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&fnof;","ƒ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Alpha;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Beta;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Gamma;","G");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Delta;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Epsilon;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Zeta;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Eta;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Theta;","T");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Iota;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Kappa;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Lambda;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Mu;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Nu;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Xi;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Omicron;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Pi;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Rho;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Sigma;","S");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Tau;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Upsilon;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Phi;","F");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Chi;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Psi;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Omega;","O");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&alpha;","a");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&beta;","ß");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&gamma;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&delta;","d");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&epsilon;","e");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&zeta;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&eta;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&theta;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&iota;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&kappa;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&lambda;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&mu;","µ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&nu;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&xi;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&omicron;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&pi;","p");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&rho;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sigmaf;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sigma;","s");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&tau;","t");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&upsilon;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&phi;","f");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&chi;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&psi;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&omega;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&thetasym;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&upsih;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&piv;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&bull;","•");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&hellip;","…");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&prime;","'");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&Prime;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&oline;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&frasl;","/");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&weierp;","P");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&image;","I");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&real;","R");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&trade;","™");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&alefsym;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&larr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&uarr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&rarr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&darr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&harr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&crarr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&lArr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&uArr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&rArr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&dArr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&hArr;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&forall;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&part;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&exist;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&empty;","Ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&nabla;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&isin;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&notin;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ni;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&prod;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sum;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&minus;","-");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&lowast;","*");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&radic;","v");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&prop;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&infin;","8");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ang;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&and;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&or;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&cap;","n");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&cup;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&int;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&there4;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sim;","~");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&cong;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&asymp;","˜");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ne;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&equiv;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&le;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&ge;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sub;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sup;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&nsub;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sube;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&supe;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&oplus;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&otimes;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&perp;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&sdot;","·");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&lceil;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&rceil;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&lfloor;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&rfloor;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&lang;","<");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&rang;",">");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&loz;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&spades;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&clubs;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&hearts;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&diams;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#38;","&");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#60;","<");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#62;",">");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#160;"," ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#161;","¡");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#162;","¢");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#163;","£");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#164;","¤");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#165;","¥");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#166;","¦");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#167;","§");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#168;","¨");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#169;","©");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#170;","ª");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#171;","«");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#172;","¬");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#173;","");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#174;","®");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#175;","¯");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#176;","°");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#177;","±");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#178;","²");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#179;","³");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#180;","´");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#181;","µ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#182;","¶");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#183;","·");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#184;","¸");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#185;","¹");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#186;","º");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#187;","»");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#188;","¼");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#189;","½");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#190;","¾");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#191;","¿");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#192;","À");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#193;","Á");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#194;","Â");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#195;","Ã");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#196;","Ä");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#197;","Å");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#198;","Æ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#199;","Ç");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#200;","È");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#201;","É");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#202;","Ê");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#203;","Ë");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#204;","Ì");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#205;","Í");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#206;","Î");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#207;","Ï");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#208;","Ð");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#209;","Ñ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#210;","Ò");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#211;","Ó");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#212;","Ô");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#213;","Õ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#214;","Ö");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#215;","×");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#216;","Ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#217;","Ù");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#218;","Ú");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#219;","Û");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#220;","Ü");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#221;","Ý");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#222;","Þ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#223;","ß");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#224;","à");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#225;","á");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#226;","â");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#227;","ã");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#228;","ä");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#229;","å");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#230;","æ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#231;","ç");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#232;","è");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#233;","é");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#234;","ê");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#235;","ë");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#236;","ì");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#237;","í");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#238;","î");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#239;","ï");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#240;","ð");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#241;","ñ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#242;","ò");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#243;","ó");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#244;","ô");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#245;","õ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#246;","ö");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#247;","÷");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#248;","ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#249;","ù");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#250;","ú");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#251;","û");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#252;","ü");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#253;","ý");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#254;","þ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#255;","ÿ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#402;","ƒ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#913;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#914;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#915;","G");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#916;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#917;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#918;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#919;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#920;","T");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#921;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#922;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#923;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#924;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#925;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#926;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#927;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#928;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#929;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#931;","S");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#932;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#933;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#934;","F");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#935;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#936;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#937;","O");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#945;","a");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#946;","ß");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#947;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#948;","d");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#949;","e");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#950;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#951;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#952;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#953;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#954;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#955;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#956;","µ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#957;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#958;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#959;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#960;","p");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#961;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#962;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#963;","s");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#964;","t");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#965;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#966;","f");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#967;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#968;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#969;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#977;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#978;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#982;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8226;","•");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8230;","…");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8242;","'");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8243;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8254;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8260;","/");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8472;","P");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8465;","I");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8476;","R");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8482;","™");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8501;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8592;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8593;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8594;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8595;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8596;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8629;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8656;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8657;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8658;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8659;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8660;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8704;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8706;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8707;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8709;","Ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8711;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8712;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8713;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8715;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8719;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8721;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8722;","-");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8727;","*");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8730;","v");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8733;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8734;","8");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8736;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8743;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8744;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8745;","n");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8746;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8747;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8756;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8764;","~");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8773;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8776;","˜");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8800;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8801;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8804;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8805;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8834;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8835;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8836;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8838;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8839;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8853;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8855;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8869;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8901;","·");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8968;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8969;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8970;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#8971;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#9001;","<");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#9002;",">");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#9674;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#9824;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#9827;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#9829;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#9830;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x26;","&");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C;","<");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3E;",">");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA0;"," ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA1;","¡");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA2;","¢");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA3;","£");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA4;","¤");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA5;","¥");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA6;","¦");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA7;","§");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA8;","¨");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xA9;","©");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xAA;","ª");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xAB;","«");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xAC;","¬");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xAD;","");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xAE;","®");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xAF;","¯");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB0;","°");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB1;","±");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB2;","²");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB3;","³");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB4;","´");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB5;","µ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB6;","¶");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB7;","·");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB8;","¸");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xB9;","¹");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xBA;","º");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xBB;","»");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xBC;","¼");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xBD;","½");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xBE;","¾");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xBF;","¿");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC0;","À");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC1;","Á");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC2;","Â");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC3;","Ã");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC4;","Ä");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC5;","Å");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC6;","Æ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC7;","Ç");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC8;","È");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xC9;","É");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xCA;","Ê");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xCB;","Ë");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xCC;","Ì");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xCD;","Í");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xCE;","Î");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xCF;","Ï");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD0;","Ð");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD1;","Ñ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD2;","Ò");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD3;","Ó");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD4;","Ô");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD5;","Õ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD6;","Ö");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD7;","×");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD8;","Ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xD9;","Ù");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xDA;","Ú");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xDB;","Û");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xDC;","Ü");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xDD;","Ý");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xDE;","Þ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xDF;","ß");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE0;","à");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE1;","á");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE2;","â");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE3;","ã");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE4;","ä");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE5;","å");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE6;","æ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE7;","ç");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE8;","è");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xE9;","é");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xEA;","ê");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xEB;","ë");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xEC;","ì");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xED;","í");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xEE;","î");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xEF;","ï");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF0;","ð");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF1;","ñ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF2;","ò");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF3;","ó");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF4;","ô");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF5;","õ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF6;","ö");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF7;","÷");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF8;","ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xF9;","ù");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xFA;","ú");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xFB;","û");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xFC;","ü");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xFD;","ý");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xFE;","þ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#xFF;","ÿ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x192;","ƒ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x391;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x392;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x393;","G");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x394;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x395;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x396;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x397;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x398;","T");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x399;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x39A;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x39B;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x39C;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x39D;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x39E;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x39F;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A0;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A1;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A3;","S");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A4;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A5;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A6;","F");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A7;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A8;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3A9;","O");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B1;","a");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B2;","ß");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B3;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B4;","d");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B5;","e");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B6;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B7;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B8;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3B9;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3BA;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3BB;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3BC;","µ");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3BD;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3BE;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3BF;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C0;","p");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C1;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C2;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C3;","s");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C4;","t");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C5;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C6;","f");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C7;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C8;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3C9;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3D1;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3D2;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x3D6;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2022;","•");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2026;","…");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2032;","'");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2033;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x203E;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2044;","/");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2118;","P");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2111;","I");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x211C;","R");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2122;","™");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2135;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2190;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2191;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2192;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2193;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2194;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x21B5;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x21D0;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x21D1;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x21D2;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x21D3;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x21D4;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2200;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2202;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2203;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2205;","Ø");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2207;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2208;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2209;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x220B;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x220F;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2211;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2212;","-");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2217;","*");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x221A;","v");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x221D;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x221E;","8");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2220;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2227;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2228;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2229;","n");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x222A;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x222B;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2234;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x223C;","~");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2245;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2248;","˜");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2260;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2261;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2264;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2265;","=");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2282;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2283;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2284;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2286;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2287;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2295;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2297;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x22A5;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x22C5;","·");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2308;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2309;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x230A;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x230B;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2329;","<");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x232A;",">");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x25CA;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2660;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2663;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2665;","?");
        str = replaceAll(str,"&#x2666;","?");

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe just add a little comment saying why this works.

Comment: This method is not fast, but it replaces every single possible charactere by its "no html" representation. Then the string is returned. No more steps. It could be improved for better performance if necessary.